# What non-parametric test to use in r for bite rate data?

Tags: r

I am new to R and statistics, and am having a hard time determining which non-parametric test is appropriate to run (data not normal/can't be transformed to fit normality).

I am looking at bite rate of fish both pre and post a treatment, and want to see if it changes significantly with the different treatments.

If anyone has any ideas of which test to use, and what variables to put where, that would be amazing.  The bite rate data is a count of total bites during a 5 minute time period, and the treatment is "period" either "pre removal" or "post removal" for two locations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a great place to ask programming questions. Please direct statistics questions to stats.stackexchange. They will probably also want more detail - it's not clear if you have 4 numbers (2 locations times 2 treatments) or if you have multiple observations of each treatment at each location.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two groups of data, each numeric but not al all normally distributed, a good first approach is the Wilcoxon rank sum test, also known as Mann-Whitney-U test. Google, whether it fits your needs. If so, use the function as follows:

Let `PRE` and `POST` be the counts in 8 intervalls, each 5 minutes.

```
PRE <- c(2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1)
POST <- c(0 ,0 ,0 ,3 ,0, 7, 8, 2)
wilcox.test(PRE, POST)
```

In the result you will want to watch out for the p-value. Usually, a difference in ranks is supposed to be significant, if the p-value is smaller then 0.05. If you want to get rid of the warnings about ties, have a look at the packages `exactRankTests`.